# When was homosexuality as the reason for institutionalization outlawed in the US?

Tags: united-states, legal-history, mental-health, insanity

In the United States, I'm guessing that one can no longer commit a person to a mental hospital (AKA insane asylum) with the only reason for commitment being: "said person is gay".

Homosexuality is no longer consider to be a mental illness; it was defined as a mental illness in the past. When was this legal change (the one in the title of this webpage) made?

Comment: Originally, committing someone to a mental institution involuntarily was generally either a) as an aspect of a court order (e.g. after a verdict of "not guilty by reason of insanity"), or b) due to diagnosis of a mental illness, although historically mental institutions have been poorly regulated and a lot of abuses have occurred. I don't have evidence, so a comment rather than an answer, but I would imagine the answer would therefore be at the time the time when homosexuality was no longer considered a crime or a mental illness.

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read our tour page.  You can see the link at the bottom of the page.